# Openlayers 3 view setProperties does not populate the map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to set my map properties dynamically but it does not work.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

I am trying to set min max zoom level like this:

```
map.getView().setProperties({minZoom: 5, maxZoom: 9});
```

This code does not set view.

I am getting map view properties, `map.getView().getProperties();` but it returns only:

[image]

I am settings extent, zoom, minZoom, maxZoom parameters but does not appear.

[DEMO APP](http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/459/)

(actually you can not set `project`, `extent`, `min`, `max zoom` and `resolutions` after map created)

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think OL only allows you to set _observable properties_ after creation. As a work-around, perhaps you could attach a handler to the ol.control.Zoom, and do the dynamic gating there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the solution from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191163/change-maxzoom-option-in-runtime-to-ol-view-in-openlayers-3/222597#222597)

You can do what you want by setting a new View in the map this way:

```
map.setView(new ol.View({
    center: map.getView().getCenter(),
    zoom: map.getView().getZoom(),
    maxZoom: 9,
    minZoom: 5
}));
```

If you want to keep all the view properties instead of assign something specific, you can get them and pass them to the new View:

```
var properties = map.getView().getProperties();
properties["minZoom"] = 5;
properties["maxZoom"] = 9;
map.setView(new ol.View(properties));
```

I updated your [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/463/)

The only view properties that you can change with `setProperties` are the ones which are listed by `getProperties`. You can of course add a new one, but the new properties `minZoom` and `maxZoom` wouldn't work as you expect here, because the map would still handle the old ones

Comment: But developers does not know this. Because `setProperties()` method is an official function that stay in api documentation, but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Default projection for map is `EPSG:3857` so change your transform in `ol.view` from `EPSG:4326` to `EPSG:3857`.  This is a common problem and ran into it myself.  If the projections don't match, nothing shows up/doesn't work.

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1zo8r5Lp/461/

Comment: I looked but `setProperties({minZoom: 5, maxZoom: 9})` does not restrict the map zoom levels between 5 and 9.